# Django: Removed Comment (is_published=False)

Tags: django

i'm trying to delete comments by using `comment.is_published=False`. But if i try to comment as the same user to the same thing with the same commenttext, it doesn't appear (probably because the commentobject already exists).

is there an other way to delete/remove a comment or what did i forget? same thing with `comment.is_removed = True`

greets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Comment model [here](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/contrib/comments/models.py) has no restrictions whatsoever on the user or text being unique, so I don't see why you would have any problem with that.

You delete a comment like you would any other object with `comment.delete()`.

But if you want to delete a queryset, say all of the comments with is_pubished = False, you will do it like this: `Comment.objects.filter(is_published=False).delete()`.

Check out the docs.

Comment: thanks mate. now i have the problem that the same user can only post the comment once. know what i mean? e.g. he can only say "yeah" to the same thing once.